# Izotope RX 2 as plugin in premier (De Hummer)

Tags: plugin

Hello All.

I have CS5, I need a de hummer within premier. The standard one is not very good. I need it in Premier Pro to speed up my work flow by applying a specific presset. I have over 400 video files however I need to remove a humming noise which is in the background.

Izotope RX 2 seems to be good however it is not a Plugin for Premier Pro from what I am aware of.

Can any one advise me of a VERY good plugin that can be used.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Hi Leon,

There was an old bug between RX 2 and Premiere Pro that prevented RX from showing up in the plug-in list.  This has been fixed on iZotope's side in the latest version of RX 2 and on Adobe's side by the latest versions of Premiere (though I'm not 100% sure if the update is in Premiere Pro CS5 or CS5.5).  Please make sure you're running the latest versions of both software packages.

Also, the RX 2 standalone app will open anything that can be opened by Quicktime codecs (it strips out the audio so you'll have to re-spot it in Premiere) and has a batch processor that will take care of all of your files in a batch (provided they have the same type of problem).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using an EQ from within Premiere? You may have luck with some surgical use of one.

Comment: I have tried, and it is not very good. Any plugin suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Rx2 can be used as standalone. 
I have used the demo on some wildly distorted thunder recordings, which were just nice after rx2, and demoed the de hummer for some pigs fx in a barn where the most annoying ac unit was going constantly. 
After rx2, it was totally gone, and no harm was done to the pigs. My jaw dropped.

Mikkel

Comment: Ok... this SOUNDS great, but as a plugin???? for Adobe Premier Pro

Comment: Well, what plugin format does Premiere support?  I'm guessing VST.  iZotope is VST-compatible (as I recall). 

Comment: Ok... Can anyone help please becuase I cannot find any informaiton on how to install a VTS plugin.. I now have Izotope